# Turn several lists into a column dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to python/dataframe and using selenium.

I'm basically going through profiles and gathering information from those profiles into their respective list.

Here is the code I currently have

```
name_list = []

name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, make_xpath_name)))
name_list.append(name)

location_list = []
location = job = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, make_xpath_location)))
location_list.append(location.text)

exp = {key: [] for key in ['job', 'company', 'date', 'job_location', 'description']}
        jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#experience)>div>ul>li')

for job in jobs:
            exp['job'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class$="t-bold"] span').text]
            exp['company'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal"] span').text]
            exp['date'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"] span').text]
            exp['job_location'] += [driver.execute_script(
                'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal t-black--light\']:nth-child(4) span")?.innerText',
                job)]
            exp['description'] += [
                driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("ul li ul span[aria-hidden=true]")?.innerText',
                                      job)]

ed = {key: [] for key in ['College', 'Degree']}
        edu = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#education)>div>ul>li')

for education in edu:
            ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold"] span').text]
            ed['Degree'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal"] span').text]
```

What I want to end up with is something at its simplest like

```
Column 1
Alice
US
SE
Amazon
3/14
Seattle
Worked as dev
Harvard
CS
```

However, Alice can have an extensive experience and education section where she has worked at multiple jobs and had several degrees. For example

```
Column 1
Alice
US
Se
Amazon
3/14
Seattle
Worked as dev
Manager
Tesla
1/01
Texas
Managed people
Harvard
CS
Harvard
HR
```

What I attempted was:

```
jobs = list(exp.values())
    educations = list(ed.values())

    dataframe_name = pd.DataFrame(name_list).T
    dataframe_location = pd.DataFrame(location_list).T

    for job in jobs:
        dataframe_jobs = pd.DataFrame(job)
    for education in educations:
        dataframe_edu = pd.DataFrame(education)

    profile_dct = [dataframe_name, dataframe_location, dataframe_jobs, dataframe_edu]
    results = pd.concat(profile_dct)

    results.to_csv('hr_profiles.csv', index=False)
```

But this is not giving me the correct output.

```
The jobs list contains:
[0] job1 job2 
[1] company1 company2
[2] dates1 date2
[3] location1, location2
[4] description1 description2
```

The education list contains

```
[0] College1 college2
[1] Degree1 degree2
```

With the above code, it gives me:

```
Column1
Name
location
description1
description2
description3
Degree
```

How do I change the list to dataset to print as columns like I need?

Comment: (1) In the for-loops, only the last job and education are saved, previous ones are thrown away. (2) Columns can only be assembled to a dataframe if they have the same length. (3) Try to add argument `axis=1` to the `pd.concat` call.

Comment: @MichaelButscher why is the for loop only saving the last job and education? I tried adding argument axis=1 to concat but it did nothing.

Comment: For each `job` one dataframe is created in the loop and assigned to `dataframe_jobs`. In the next iteration a new dataframe is created and assigned to `dataframe_jobs` which overwrites the previous assignment. Only the last dataframe is stored. Same for education.

Comment: Is it the exactly same result with `axis=1` in the `concat` call?